# Find out why something didnt match in complex sql query?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

i have a really complicated SQL query with alots of where conditions (all are ands) and i have some data. Sometimes some entries are not fetched when executing the sql query, which is fine and **expected**. But from a business point of view we need to know **why** it doesnt match.

Is there any utility method, sql trick or anything to make the debugging in such cases easier? Its a really long query and we have to basically go through each field and check for the values which is time consuming.

I tried to google, but i only get some error messages

EDIT: one thing i forgott to add, is that the query is dynamically generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get debugging information is to build a query from the parts of your `WHERE` clause. For example, for this table and query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (a int, b varchar(10), c int, d bool);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 'hello', 34, true),
(2, 'bye', 12, false),
(3, 'bye', 19, true),
(3, 'hello', 0, true);
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE a > 1 
  AND b != 'bye'
  AND c < 20
  AND d
```

The output is:

```
a   b       c   d
3   hello   0   t
```

We can figure out why the other rows didn't match using this query:

```
SELECT
  concat_ws(', ',
    CASE WHEN a > 1 THEN NULL ELSE 'A <= 1' END,
    CASE WHEN b != 'bye' THEN NULL ELSE 'B = ''bye''' END,
    CASE WHEN c < 20 THEN NULL ELSE 'C >= 20' END,
    CASE WHEN d THEN NULL ELSE 'D is false' END
  ) AS reasons
FROM test
```

Output for my sample data:

```
reasons
A <= 1, C >= 20
B = 'bye', D is false
B = 'bye'
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/iJIjTQv_)

Comment: thanks for your answer, one requirement i forgot is that we dynamically create this sql statement so preparing a single sql statement beforehand is not possible and dynamically creating such debugging queries is timeconsuming aswell :/

Comment: @KP_EV if you have to "basically go through each field and check for the values" couldn't you just spend that time editing your dynamically created query into something like this?

Comment: @KP_EV how exactly is the query generated?

Comment: Query is generated by our own code, via if else etc because of reasons. Yes i can spend the time writing custom sql, but iam searching for a longterm solution to this problem

Comment: Then you *could* use your own code to generate this query instead, and get all the results and then filter in java to only use the results where the length of `reasons` is `0`. Anyway, just trying to offer some ideas...

Comment: yeah thanks :) .

Comment: @KP_EV don't accept the answer. If you do, it's unlikely you'll get any other suggestions.